# eps/pdf figures not shown with XeLaTeX (with WinEdt)

Tags: graphics, xetex

I have a trouble in including eps/pdf files using XeLaTeX.

It only give a white patch where the figure supposed to be if I compile with WinEdt 8 (Build: 20130513 (v. 8.0) - 64-bit), without any error/warning message.

Same files worked well a year ago. I tried to execute the old tex files but only get a white patch of figures now. I tried another computer with WinEdt 9 and it works. But it doesn't work with WinEdt 9 in my computer. Same figures work with PDFTeXify.

Fortunately, it works well with TeXworks Version 0.4.5 r.1280.

All things above suggest there is something in WinEdt is wrong. It is very strange because I didn't change any setting of LaTeX and WinEdt.

My system is Windows 7 professional + MiKTeX 2.9.

Here is my sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{epstopdf} % with/without is the same

\begin{document}
Result compiled with XeLaTeX:
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{fig1}
  \caption{A figure is supposed to show above}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is the results given by two tex editor:
[image]

As requested, this is my log file:

```
    This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-0.9998 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2013.5.20)  27 MAY 2015 12:30
entering extended mode
**test.tex
("C:\Users\User1\Dropbox\Research\test\test.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic, 
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2012-05-30, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2012-05-30, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 91.

("C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.de
f"
File: xetex.def 2013/04/29 v0.96 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
) ("C:\Users\User1\Dropbox\Research\test\test.aux")
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
File: fig1.pdf Graphic file (type QTm)

<use  "fig1.pdf" > [1

] ("C:\Users\User1\Dropbox\Research\test\test.aux") ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 544 strings out of 429035
 6095 string characters out of 3167909
 53968 words of memory out of 3000000
 3861 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 912 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 25i,5n,19p,181b,209s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

The settings in winedt-options-execution modes-xelatex:
[image]

The diagnosis:

```
WinEdt and External Applications

WinEdt does its best to detect your TeX System and accessories from your PATH and Windows Registry. With properly installed accessories no changes to WinEdt's default settings should be required in order to have a fully operational interface to your TeX System.

This report shows what WinEdt found in your Registry. It also suggests possible solutions to remedy any problem with finding and launching external applications. Although it is possible to manually correct certain locations (such as TeX Root folder) it is best to ensure that your software is properly installed and let WinEdt automatically detect all the executables. This allows for smooth upgrades.

If you need further assistance, include this report in your support request. Do not, however, expect any miracles: if WinEdt could not find any trace of your TeX System or other accessories they are probably not properly installed. Reinstalling the problematic software and restarting WinEdt after that might be by far the best way to resolve the situation...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

File: "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 8\TeX.log"
Date: Wednesday, May 27, 2015  12:36

Summary :-)
===========

Your TeX installation appears to be fine. If you experience problems after an application has been launched this usually isn't a WinEdt-related matter. In such case, you should test a problematic application from the Command Prompt, consult the documentation that comes with your (TeX) software, and try to locate the real source of your problem...
________________________________________________________________________________

WinEdt 8  (v. 8.0)  [Build: 20130513]

Caption: WinEdt 8.0
Default Mode: TeX
Default Type: .tex
Default Path: %P

*** OS: Windows 6.1 [Build: 7601] Service Pack 1
*** Account (UAC) Status: Restricted User
*** Configuration: Default:MiKTeX
*** TeX System: MiKTeX
*** User Profile: Enabled
*** %B: C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 8
*** %b: C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 8

*** WinEdt  PATH: 
"C:\Program Files\WinEdt Team\WinEdt 8;
 C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Xpdf\bin64;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2011 SP1\redist\intel64\mkl;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2011 SP1\redist\ia32\mkl;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\mpirt;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\mpirt;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\compiler;
 C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2\Bin\;
 c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
 c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
 C:\Windows\system32;
 C:\Windows;
 C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
 c:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP Performance Advisor;
 C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
 C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
 C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;
 C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\Commands;
 c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
 c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
 c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
 c:\Python33\;
 C:\emacs-22.3\bin\;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin;
 C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\bin\x64\"

*** Windows PATH: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xpdf\bin64;
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2011 SP1\redist\intel64\mkl;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2011 SP1\redist\ia32\mkl;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\mpirt;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\mpirt;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\ia32\compiler;
 C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft HPC Pack 2008 R2\Bin\;
 c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
 c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
 C:\Windows\system32;
 C:\Windows;
 C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
 c:\Program Files (x86)\Hewlett-Packard\HP Performance Advisor;
 C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
 C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
 C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\;
 C:\SIMULIA\Abaqus\Commands;
 c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
 c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
 c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
 c:\Python33\;
 C:\emacs-22.3\bin\;
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
 C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2014b\bin;
 C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\bin\x64\"

________________________________________________________________________________

Searching for Executables:
==========================

WinEdt will try to locate external executables based on the PATH Environment Variable and Windows Registry. If some components are not found follow the instructions. Some applications such as, for example, GS or GSView are optional; you can safely ignore any messages about the "missing" accessories that you are not intending to use...

TeX-Root: OK
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9
TeX-Bin:  OK
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64

TeX-Help Folder: OK
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc

DVIView: OK (PATH yap.exe)*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\yap.exe

TeX-Bin (TeX.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\tex.exe
TeX-Bin (LaTeX.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe
TeX-Bin (PDFTeX.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdftex.exe
TeX-Bin (PDFLaTeX.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe
TeX-Bin (BibTeX.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\bibtex.exe
TeX-Bin (dvips.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\dvips.exe
TeX-Bin (ps2pdf.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\ps2pdf.exe
TeX-Bin (dvipdfmx.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\dvipdfmx.exe
TeX-Bin (mf.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\mf.exe
TeX-Bin (mpost.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\mpost.exe

MiKTeX-Bin (TeXify.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe


GS-Bin: (gswin64c.exe): OK*
  C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.10\bin\gswin64c.exe

GSView: OK (REG)
  "C:\Program Files\Ghostgum\gsview\gsview64.exe"
  C:\PROGRA~1\Ghostgum\gsview\gsview64.exe

PDF Viewer (PDF-View): OK (REG)
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
  C:\PROGRA~2\Adobe\READER~1.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe

================================================================================

Help in this interface contains additional guidelines on how to correct the most commonly encountered problems and how to further customize and configure external applications that are launched from WinEdt...

================================================================================
```

Comment: Why don't you try to see what happens if you install latest version of WinEdt (`9.1`)?

Comment: Show the log-file. Show your settings in winedt-options-execution modes-xelatex. Check in execution modes the tab "diagnosis".

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. I've updated the setting you requested.

Comment: There is nothing that suggests that winedt is faulty somehow. How are you viewing the pdf produced by winedt/xelatex? Did you try another viewer?